# How to create a message every time an event is emitted

Tags: javascript, algorithm, events

I'm trying to implement an app that creates a ".message" for each lyric every time the beat ticks. However, it seems like I've hit a wall while trying to come up with an algorithm.

My code:

```
import EventEmitter from "eventemitter3";
import Beat from "./Beat";

export default class Application extends EventEmitter {
  static get events() {
    return {
      READY: "ready",
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this._beat = new Beat();
    this._create();

    this.emit(Application.events.READY);
  }
  _create() {
    const lyrics = ["Ah", "ha", "ha", "ha", "stayin' alive", "stayin' alive"];
    let count = 0;

    this._beat.on("update", (bit) => {
      const message = document.createElement("div");
      message.classList.add("message");
      message.innerText = lyrics[bit];

      document.querySelector(".main").appendChild(message);
    })
  }
}
```

Beat interval:

```
import EventEmitter from "eventemitter3";
export default class Beat extends EventEmitter{
  static get events() {
    return {
      BIT: "bit",
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log("bit");
      this.emit(Beat.events.BIT);
    }, 600);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're subscribing to `'update'` event, which is never fired.

Fixed code snippet:

```js
    this._beat.on(Beat.events.BIT, (bit) => {
      const message = document.createElement("div");
      message.classList.add("message");
      message.innerText = lyrics[bit];

      document.querySelector(".main").appendChild(message);
    })
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted! However, the validator which I have to use gives me an error https://gitlab.com/boomdotdev/validator/-/jobs/1603099801

Comment: @koko you can try different ways of attaching a listener. Like replacing "on" with "addListener".
I don't lnow how the validator works internally. But the code is already doing exactly what it's asking for.